# iTerm/zsh not reading .bashrc OR .bash_profile

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, zsh, bashrc

In `~/.bash_profile`
I have :

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

In `~/.bashrc` I have some aliases

When I load a new iTerm window, my aliases do not work. If I source `~/.bashrc` they work. If I source `~.bash_profile` they work.

Isn't at least one of these supposed to be sourced automatically?

What might be causing it not to work properly?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The answer is simple, almost evident in the question. Here's why:

The shell `zsh` is not `bash`, it is a different shell. `zsh` will not use the default files built for `bash`: `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. These two files are startup configuration files for `bash`. `zsh` has its own startup configuration files.

You can find out more about them here on the `zsh` [intro page](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html):

> There are five startup files that zsh will read commands from:
>
> ```
> $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv
> $ZDOTDIR/.zprofile
> $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc
> $ZDOTDIR/.zlogin
> $ZDOTDIR/.zlogout
> ```

You had mentioned your aliases don't work, to fix this, apply your aliases here like so:

`~/.zshrc`

```
alias sz='source ~/.zshrc'     # Easily source your ~/.zshrc file.
alias ls='pwd; ls --color'     # Alias 'ls' to: pwd + ls + color.
```

Comment: Thank you. Note that `ls --color` gave me `illegal option` in both `bash` and `zsh` on OSX 10.10, but not on Linux -- I'll look into it. Cheers.

Comment: I don't have a Mac to test on but I think this has to do with the ls implementation on OS X, I don't think it has the  - -color argument. If I remember I'll look it up.

Comment: "... zsh has its own startup configuration files." this is what he probably asks for huh? just say "dude, it is ~/.zshrc".

Comment: +1 great tips in the answer for macOS Catalina now using zsh officially. Thank you.

Comment: For macOS, use `ls -G` insted of `ls --color`

Answer (score 39):

If you are using zsh then to force source `.bash_profile`

in `~/.zshrc` add the line below

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

P.S - I havent investigated whether this can cause any problem.

Comment: I guess this answer would be helpful after release of macOS 10.5 Catalina in order to port bash_profile from bash to zsh.

Comment: Fast and effective!

Comment: Note this is very bad idea if your `.bash_profile` calls `source .bashrc`. Then you'll have a zsh shell loading a bunch of bash code and probably do weird behavior.

Comment: @cgnorthcutt Why is loading bash code a problem? If it's just setting up some simple aliases, for example.

Comment: @JamesKoss Say the next day you install a program that modifies your .bashrc to loop over a bunch of other aliases to add. Oops... zsh and bash use different looping indices, and now your .zshrc is broken.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the lines from **~/.bash_profile** to **~/.zshrc**

```
cat ~/.bash_profile >> ~/.zshrc
```

And open a new terminal tab/window or use `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: This deleted all my ~/.zshrc previous contents.

Comment: @GerardReches Sorry for the mess. In my case, I didn't have `~/.zshrc` so `>` will create and add the lines from `~/.bash_profile`. you should have used `>>` update operator to append `~/.zshrc.